# SQLite not returning result when using AND

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am having a very puzzling question. When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.pid FROM posts 
INNER JOIN questions 
ON questions.pid = posts.pid 
INNER JOIN tags 
ON tags.pid = posts.pid 
WHERE tags.tag = 'Relational' COLLATE NOCASE;
```

Where it select posts with the tag "Relational", it is able to return the id of:
001, 002, 014, 015. Now when I execute the query that extracts another tag like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.pid FROM posts 
INNER JOIN questions 
ON questions.pid = posts.pid 
INNER JOIN tags 
ON tags.pid = posts.pid 
WHERE tags.tag = 'Database' COLLATE NOCASE;
```

It is able to return 001, 002, 003, 009, 015, 022. It should be clear that id 001, 002 and 015 are the overlapping ids, and therefore when I use the AND operator it should be my expected return. However when I execute the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.pid FROM posts 
INNER JOIN questions 
ON questions.pid = posts.pid 
INNER JOIN tags 
ON tags.pid = posts.pid 
WHERE tags.tag = 'Relational' COLLATE NOCASE
AND tags.tag = 'Database' COLLATE NOCASE;
```

I get an empty result. I have tried a lot of things including adding brackets around the conditions and the AND clause, I cannot fix this problem. Anyone knows what is the cause?

Answer (score 1):

You want aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT q.pid
FROM questions q
     tags t
     ON t.pid = q.pid
WHERE t.tag IN ('Relational' COLLATE NOCASE, 'Database' COLLATE NOCASE)
GROUP BY q.pid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you are only trying to get the post id, there is no need to join in the `posts` table.

The version with `AND` cannot work.  The `WHERE` clause works only on one row at a time and the `tag` cannot have two values in the same row.